# Why doesn't Material UI use my custom theme palette colors?

Tags: material-ui, themes

I want to use a custom palette so that my site uses brand colors across all components.  I want to be able to access these custom colors globally, including in `makeStyles`.

This is my theme file:

```
import { createMuiTheme }  from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#467f0f'
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

This is my component:

```
import theme from './theme';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  title: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(2),
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: theme.spacing(1),
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    fontSize: theme.spacing(4),
    margin: theme.spacing(2, 'auto'),
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    textAlign: 'center',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      fontSize: theme.spacing(8),
    },
  },
}));

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          variant='h1'
        >
          My App
        </Typography>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

There are no errors being thrown or linter warnings or anything.  But the color from my custom palette is not being used.  What might I have missed along the way?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't working is because when your `ThemeProvider` is in the same component as your `useStyles`. So what is happening is you are trying to use your theme before it has actually been added to the rest of your app.

So what you might need to do is either import your `ThemeProvider` one level higher (I assume your index.js file), or have a child component inside ThemeProvider which renders your children, which is the example I have given below

```js
import theme from './theme';

function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppContent/>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  title: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(2),
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: theme.spacing(1),
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    fontSize: theme.spacing(4),
    margin: theme.spacing(2, 'auto'),
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    textAlign: 'center',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      fontSize: theme.spacing(8),
    },
  },
}));


function AppContent(): JSX.Element {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Typography
      className={classes.title}
      variant='h1'
    >
      My App
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

Also Rather then `createMuiTheme` try just `createTheme` It seems that it was renamed in one of the newer releases to make clearer

```js
import { createTheme }  from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#467f0f'
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

And on another note. I would recommend not styling the typography that much other than things like color, fontSize, etc. Rather think about wrapping it in a `Box` and having that have the styles for the backgroundColor, borderRadius, etc